# Return an Array from a function C: Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

Tags: c

I need to return the value of the matrix, but I am gettin this error

```
Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
```

in:

```
qk_output[m][o] = 0;
```

and

```
qk_output[m][o] += queries[m][n] * keys[n][o];
```

Could anyone help me?  Thanks!

```
int* multmm(int queries[M][N], int keys[N][O]) {
  // Matrix Multiplication
  int* qk_output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) *M*N);
  for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {

    for (int o = 0; o < O; o ++) {
      qk_output[m][o] = 0;

      for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        qk_output[m][o] += queries[m][n] * keys[n][o];
      }
    }
  }
 return qk_output;
}
```

Comment: what are the values of M N O?

Comment: `qk_output` is not a 2D array. `qk_output` is an `int*`. Thus `qk_output[m]` is an `int`, and `qk_output[m][o]` is invalid.

Comment: If you are going to use a flat 1D array and simulate a 2D array, you need to change `qk_output[m][o]` to `qk_output[m * N + o]`

Comment: The values are specific in the library

Answer (score 1):

```
int* qk_output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) *M*N);
```

`qk_output` is a pointer to an `int`

the compiler knows how to access `qk_output[n]` but doesn't know how to access `qk_output[m][n]`, you need to switch to:

```
int (*qk_output)[N] = malloc(sizeof(*qk_output) * M); // Don't cast malloc
```

that is, a pointer to an array of `N`  `int`s

Now the compiler has enough information to access `qk_output[m][n]`

For the return question: you can use `void *multmm(...)` or `int (*multmm(...))[N]`, the second one gives more information to the compiler so it is less error prone.

Something like:

```
int (*multmm(int queries[M][N], int keys[N][O]))[N]
{
    int (*qk_output)[N] = malloc(sizeof(*qk_output) * M);
    ...
    return qk_output;
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*arr2D)[N] = multmm(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but, I still have a similar error, in the malloc line copying the same code you mentioned here.
Error:
ERROR: [HLS 207-2754] cannot initialize a variable of type 'int (*)[2]' with an rvalue of type 'void *'

(I have tried to do the casting in the malloc also and I get the same error)

Comment: It should workd: https://ideone.com/VlDTzy Try to extract a short fragment and it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

To return a 2D array from a function, you can do

```
#define N 4
#define M 3

int (*foo(void ))[N]
{
    int (*p)[N] = malloc(M * sizeof *p);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            p[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main (void){
    int (*mat)[N] = foo();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    
    free(mat);
    return 0;   
}
```